# Scraping with nested for loops exhibits weird behavior in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape hockey data for `2000-2001`, `2001-2002`, `2002-2003` seasons, where each season contains tables distributed over many pages. Here is my scraping function (`ushl_scrape`):

```
ushl_scrape <- function(season, page) {

  # Set url of webpage
  custom_url <- paste0("https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/ushl/stats/", season, "?sort=ppg&page=", page)

  # Scrape
  url <- read_html(custom_url)

  ushl <- url %>% 
    html_node(xpath = "/html/body/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    filter(Player != "") %>% 
    mutate(season = season)

  # Return table
  ushl
}
```

I then use this for loop to run `ushl_scrape` over 3 different seasons. To explain this for loop, since I don't know how many pages of data each season is distributed over, I scrape data over pages 1:10 and once I hit a page with 0 rows, I move on to the next year

```
# Total years
total_years <- paste0(2000:2002, "-", 2001:2003)

# Page
page_num <- c(1:10)

final_list <- vector("list", length = length(total_years))
by_year <- vector("list")


for (ii in seq_along(total_years)) {

  # Sleep for 2 seconds to not bombard server
  Sys.sleep(2)

  for (jj in seq_along(page_num)) {

    Sys.sleep(2)

    # Scrape season[ii] and page_num[jj]
    scraped_table <- ushl_scrape(season = total_years[ii], page = page_num[jj])

    # If scraped table has no rows, exit for loop!
    if (nrow(scraped_table) == 0) {
      break
    } else{
      by_year[[jj]] <- scraped_table
    }
  }

  # Store final_df inside final_list
  final_df <- bind_rows(by_year)
  final_list[[ii]] <- final_df

}

# Finally, bind rows all the elements in list
scraped_df <- bind_rows(final_list)
```

In `scraped_df`, I see all three seasons worth of data, but at the end, I see repetitive `2001-2002` season data added...

1. Why did my for loop add the 2001-2002 season data at the end?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there were some rows repeated. Running your code as it is gave 46 duplicate rows.

```
sum(duplicated(scraped_df))
#[1] 46
```

The issue was you had to initialise `by_year` for every `total_year` inside your outer `for` loop. Since you were not doing that it was not clearing the `by_year` value from the previous iteration and hence the duplication.

```
for (ii in seq_along(total_years)) {

  # Sleep for 2 seconds to not bombard server
  Sys.sleep(2)
  by_year <- vector("list") # <- Added this line
  for (jj in seq_along(page_num)) {    
      Sys.sleep(2)

     # Scrape season[ii] and page_num[jj]
     scraped_table <- ushl_scrape(season = total_years[ii], page = page_num[jj])
      #browser()
     # If scraped table has no rows, exit for loop!
     if (nrow(scraped_table) == 0) {
        break
     } else{
         by_year[[jj]] <- scraped_table
     }
   }

 # Store final_df inside final_list
 final_df <- bind_rows(by_year)
 final_list[[ii]] <- final_df

}

scraped_df <- bind_rows(final_list)
```

We can check for duplicate rows now

```
sum(duplicated(scraped_df))
#[1] 0
```